# *this and const member functions

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use the this pointer to assign the data from a calling object to one declared in a const member function?  Something like:

(assuming I've already built SomeClass)

```
void func() const
{
    SomeClass object1;

    object1 = *this;
}

int main()
{
    SomeClass object2;

    object2.func();

    return 0;
}
```

I know the above function is pointless.  I'm just wondering if it's a legal assignment using *this.

Comment: Can't you just compile the code and see what happens?

Comment: You're only reading from the `*this` object, so can't see why it should be a problem.

Comment: http://ideone.com is your friend :)

Comment: ideone.com is great!  Thanks Carl.

Yeah, it looks like this is fine.  I was getting a compiler error in my program because I forgot the binary scope resolution operator and I thought it had something to do with const member functions because I'm using them for the first time.  Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is fine, so long as SomeClass has a copy assignment operator. The const on the member function declares that you will not change the state of the object: func() doesn't do this, so it is legal code. There are ways of subverting const if you try hard enough, however,  this is not one of them.